# A good algorithm for getting fallowing combination of elements

Tags: c++, performance, combinations

I try to write an application which will have a function called 'special_reorder' and is the core of my application. Perhaps it's the most complicated function in my app. This function is a class member of a class similar to std::map, however it doesn't automatically sort contained elements. After function call such class object should be recreated the way that map elements are put into next diffrent order. The thing I want to accomplish is that every next function call should make next unique elements sequence diffrent then any previous to appear in this object until the function has been called n times where n is a number of all diffrent combinations. I'm weak in maths, but I know that number of permutations is x! = n where x is a number of elements in the map. I want this function to be not so slow. I think that keys should be mainly utilized for reordering because they are of type short in the class instance in my app.

Here is a class code:

```
#ifndef MY_MAP_H
#define MY_MAP_H

template<typename A, typename B>
class my_map
{
    private:
    int count, len ;
    A *keys ;
    B *values ;

    void resizeContent()
    {
        A *new_k = new A[len * 2] ;
        B *new_val = new B[len * 2] ;
        for(int aa = 0; aa < len; aa++)
        {
            new_k[aa] = keys[aa] ;
            new_val[aa] = values[aa] ;
            delete[] keys ;
            delete[] values ;
            keys = new_k ;
            values = new_val ;
            len *= 2 ;
        }
    }

    public:
    my_map()
    {
        count = 0 ;
        len = 10 ;
        keys = new A[len] ;
        values = new B[len] ;
    }
    ~my_map()
    {
        delete[] keys ;
        delete[] values ;
    }

    void special_reorder()
    {

    }

    int size()
    {
        return count ;
    }

    void replace(int first, int second)
    {
        if(first >= count || second >= count || first < 0 || second < 0)
        return ;
        A k_tmp = keys[first] ;
        B v_tmp = values[first] ;
        keys[first] = keys[second] ;
        values[first] = values[second] ;
        keys[second] = k_tmp ;
        values[second] = v_tmp ;
    }

    void insert(A key, B val)
    {
        if(count == len)
        resizeContent() ;
        keys[count] = key ;
        values[count++] = val ;
    }

    B& operator[] (const int index)
    {
        return values[index] ;
    }
} ;

#endif
```

Please help me implement that function or give me some good idea of how to do this.

Comment: What about unordered_map? Why not use vectors for your internal arrays?

Comment: unsorted_map is supported by c++11 and I'm using older compiler

Comment: You can get free implementations of this data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using c++ consider

**std::next_permutation**

as a solution to your issue.